# How to export a TypeScript project from StackBlitz

Tags: typescript, stackblitz

Is there a way to export a TypeScrpit project created on StackBlitz using the "TypeScript Blank Project" template and run it anywhere else?

If you just download it, you will get an empty package.json with no run scripts or devDependencies.

What does StackBlitz use under the hood for module resolution? Is it webpack or something else?

Comment: hi man, same trouble here - did you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Click on `Project` and then on the cloud with the arrow down in it:
[image]